# Spring boot 独自Validatorの作成でエラーが発生します。

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

いつもお世話になっております。
SpringBootアプリケーションを実行しますと、
以下エラーが発せします。
原因がわかりませんので、ご存知の方がいらっしゃれば対応方法を教えてください。

【エラー】

```
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.sample.MyData] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='電話番号の入力が不正です。', propertyPath=memo, rootBeanClass=class com.sample.MyData, messageTemplate='電話番号の入力が不正です。'}
]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
```

【Phone.javaの内容】

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy=PhoneValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ReportAsSingleViolation
public @interface Phone {
    String message() default "電話番号の入力が不正です。";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default{};
    boolean onlyNumber() default false;
}
```

【PhoneValidator .javaの内容】

```
public class PhoneValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Phone, String> {
    private boolean onlyNumber = true;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Phone phone){
        this.onlyNumber=phone.onlyNumber();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String input,ConstraintValidatorContext cxt){
        if(input == null){
            return false;
        }
        if(this.onlyNumber){
            return input.matches("[0-9]*");
        }
        else{
            return input.matches("[0-9()-]*");
        }
    }
}
```

【MyData.java】の内奥

```
public class MyData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column(length=50,nullable=false)
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable=true)
    private Integer age;

    @Column(length=200,nullable=true)
    private String mail;

    @Column(nullable=true)
    @Phone(onlyNumber=true) // ←左記の記述を@Phoneにするエラーは発生しません。
    private String memo;
```

以上です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `memo`に与えた入力内容(`PhoneValidator`でチェックした内容)を示した方がよいと思います。

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。PhoneValidatorの処理内容は記述しておりますが、何か足りないでしょうか？

Comment: 入力内容があれば、特定の入力で発生するのか等、原因特定のヒントになるかと思い提案しました。

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。入力内容は何もありません。上記プログラムをSTSで開発しているので、該当のプロジェクトを選んで、右クリック、実行、springbootアプリケーションを選んだらご連絡しましたエラーが出力されました。

Comment: 原因が分かりましたので、ご連絡いたします。私のプログラムミスで問題が発生しておりました。